# "borrowed value does not live long enough" seems to blame the wrong thing

Tags: rust

I am counting the number of times a word appears in Macbeth:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("macbeth.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();

    for l in reader.lines() {
        for w in l.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
            let count = counts.entry(w).or_insert(0);
            *count += 1;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", counts);
}
```

Rust barfs on this, saying:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
11 |         for w in l.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
   |                  ---------- temporary value created here
...
14 |         }
   |         ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
...
18 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

The actual problem is that `w` is a reference, and so changing it to `w.to_string()` solves it. I don't get why the Rust compiler is pointing the blame at `l`, when the issue is `w`. How am I supposed to infer that `w` is the problem here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> is pointing the blame at `l`

It's not, really. Review the error message again:

```
     for w in l.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
              ---------- temporary value created here
```

The error marker is pointing to the call of `unwrap` on `l`.

> when the issue is `w`

It's not, really. `l` is of type `Result<String>`. When you call `unwrap`, you get a `String`, and then `split_whitespace` returns references to that string. These references live only as long as the string, but your code tries to put them into a hashmap that will live longer than the string. The problem is that the *`l.unwrap()`* doesn't live long enough, and `w` is just a reference to the thing that doesn't live long enough.

Conceptually, it's the same problem as this code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();

    {
        let s = String::from("hello world");
        counts.insert(&s, 0);
    }

    println!("{:?}", counts);
}
```

Which also points to `s` and says it doesn't live long enough (because it doesn't).

The correct solution is to convert each word into an owned `String` which the `HashMap` can then hold:

```
for l in reader.lines() {
    for w in l.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
        counts.entry(w.to_string()).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is both right and wrong here. `l` is blamed, because `w` lives only as long as `l` (and `l.unwrap()`) and `l` doesn't live long enough to put it in hashmap in a higher scope.

In practice, you just have to look at what other variables depend on the lifetime of a variable the compiler complains about.

But Rust is also working lately on improving error reporting, so I'd [raise this case as potential bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/).