# Lack of lifetime of line from buffered reader prevents splitting line

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I am banging my head trying to figure out Rust's borrowing/lifetime/ownership properties. Namely, when using a buffered reader, and attempting to split a line. The code

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("foo.txt").expect("file not found");
    let f = BufReader::new(f);

    for line in f.lines() {
        let split: Vec<&str> = {
            let ln: String = line.unwrap();
            ln.split(' ').collect()
        };
    }
}
```

or any variation of (with or without specifying variable type, futile attempts to make it mutable, etc) results in:

```
'ln' does not live long enough; borrowed value must only be valid for the static lifetime...
```

yet trying to maybe fake an extended lifetime and grab some data out of the line via a slice

```
let nm = line;
name = &line[..];
```

or even just trying to operate the `split()` on the unmodified line variable results in:

```
cannot index into a value of type 'std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>'
```

["borrowed value does not live long enough" seems to blame the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264396/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-seems-to-blame-the-wrong-thing) suggests that the lifetime lasts long enough to put each word into its own string, but modifying my original code on [the  Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3208b6f3b653176aa3ee6bb3c68eb335&version=stable) to include that nested for loop still results in a

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
11 |         for w in line.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
14 |         }
   |         - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
15 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

in reference to the `line.unwrap()`

Ultimately, what am I misunderstanding here about Rust's lifetime or borrowing properties?

Comment: The error you have here is not [the error that your code creates](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3b3aeb252dc73484645534863cbfc2d0&version=stable). Please review how to create a [MCVE] that accurately recreates your problem. Namely, the error has nothing about `'static`.

Comment: Do you feel that [error: `line` does not live long enough but it's ok in playground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37264396/155423) answers your question?

Comment: Or even better: [“borrowed value does not live long enough” seems to blame the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37264396/155423). If not, please [edit] your question to explain the difference.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to explain what you don't understand about the error message that you get from the compiler? For whatever reason, you have been only pasting one line of each of the error messages; I've pasted the entire error in, which seems pretty lucid and descriptive. Also, you are asking about an error that mentions the `'static` lifetime, but *none of the code you've provided has that error*. We cannot help you fix an error that we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

The error your original code gives when compiled is:

```
error[E0597]: `ln` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
11 |             ln.split(' ').collect()
   |             ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |         };
   |         - `ln` dropped here while still borrowed
13 |     }
   |     - borrowed value needs to live until here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

As per @shepmasters comments it is a good idea to provide the full error when posting a question.

Anyway, it highlights the problem:

```
let split: Vec<&str> = {
    let ln: String = line.unwrap();
    ln.split(' ').collect()
};
```

You are creating a `Vec` containing references to `str` slices; slices don't own the data that they are sliced from, they are effectively pointers into data which has to be owned by another variable. Therefore the variable that they are sliced from have to outlive the slices.

Inside the expression you are using to initialise the  `Vec`, you create a `String` containing the line of text that you are processing. The scope of this string is the variable `ln` is the initialisation expression - it will be dropped as soon as you leave that scope.

Then you `split` the string, which returns an iterator to string slices, one per substring. Remember though, the iterator is returning slices, which are pointers to the substrings in the `String` `ln`. Those slices are not allowed to outlive `ln` itself.

Hopefully you can see the problem now. As soon as you exit the initialisation expression, `ln` is dropped, but the `Vec` would still contain the `str` slices. What are they pointing to?

The fix is very simple. Why declare `ln` inside that block? In fact why have a block there at all? This works:

```
for line in f.lines() {
    let ln: String = line.unwrap();
    let split: Vec<&str> = ln.split(' ').collect();
    // Now do something with split
}
```